# Should I include stdafx.h within my static library? What format should my library be?

Tags: static-libraries, precompiled-headers, stdafx.h

I am creating a static library. I have gone through the win32 application, static library, no precompiled headers. The file is a .cpp I am assuming that I can export this to the actual .lib file, or is it suppose to be .lib from the start?

Also, I keep getting the cannot open source file stdafx.h, which I have included within my main static library .cpp file. Tell me, am I suppose to do this?

Thanks